# restrict user to one region AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, policy

I want to restrict users to only one region.

I know that using IAM policy and group can be done, but it something that can be forgotten when create new users or role.

I am looking something like Service Control Policies (SCP), but  I only have one AWS account which is not possible to use SCP (it wont affect the management account).

or maybe there are some sort of lambda function to archive this scenario or maybe another solution would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You already asked similar question before. You got correct answer for that, which you didn't accept. What's wrong with that answer?

Comment: I am looking for something proper, not manually attach IAM policy or group everytime there is new users or roles.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup alerts using AWS Config or schedule lambda which will check and notify, but AWS Organisation and SCP is the best way.

Comment: I am agree SCP is the best way, but I only have one AWS account and as per the documentation, it wont affect the management/master account.

Comment: create new master account, and invite the existing one. it will solve that issue, cost nothing and allow for a lot more options.